# Perl Match Operator =~

Tags: perl

This is a very basic question but I am not able to find any proper documentation explaining this behaviour.

`("Johnson" =~ /son/ )` returns true but `(/son/ =~ "Johnson")` returns false. What is the exact reason? Why =~ operator behaves differently when the operands are interchanged?

Comment: It's mentioned in the docs I found using Google http://www-cgi.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/user/rgs/mosaic/pl-exp-op.html. Why didn't that work out for you?

Comment: http://learn.perl.org

Comment: Related: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators

Comment: Your question is equivalent to: "**I get 3 when I divide 15 by 5. But, when I divide 5 by 15, I don't get 3. How can this be?!**"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

STRAIGHT OUTTA DOCS:

> The simplest regexp is simply a word, or more generally, a string of
>   characters. A regexp consisting of a word matches any string that
>   contains that word:

```
"Hello World" =~ /World/;  # matches
```

> What is this Perl statement all about? `"Hello World"` is a simple double-quoted string. `World` is
>   the regular expression and the `//` enclosing `/World/` tells Perl to
>   search a string for a match. **The operator `=~` associates the string
>   with the regexp match and produces a true value if the regexp matched**,
>   or false if the regexp did not match. In our case, `World` matches the
>   second word in `"Hello World"` , so the expression is true.

Please read http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html

---

Now in your example `"Johnson" =~ /son/` matches because RHS of `=~` (which is son) is found in LHS (Johnson). In case of `/son/ =~ "Johnson"` RHS (Johnson) is not found in LHS (son).

Answer (score 3):

Well... because the =~ operator binds a scalar expression, to a pattern match.

So it states the order in which the arguments need to be given. Your second `(/son/ =~ "Johnson")` uses Johnson as pattern... and that one is not hit, thus false.

See binding operators: https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/PERL/node87.html